# Почему следующий код возвращает ошибку

Tags: c#

WorkingClass - статический класс,в который вложен класс member,в который вложен массив List экземпляров класса Loan.
            WorkingClass.cs

```
 public static class WorkingClass
{
    public static Member member;
}
```

Member.cs

```
    public class Member
{
    public List<Loan> activeLoans =new List<Loan> { };
}
```

Почему следующий код возвращает ошибку?

```
        Loan loan = new Loan();
        WorkingClass.member.activeLoans.Add(loan);
```

Comment: Какое исключение вы получаете?

Comment: И я так понимаю member не вложенный класс, а член

Comment: @D.Stark Забыл указать исключение "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы не создали экземпляр списка:

```
public class WorkingClass
{
  public class member
  {
    public static List<Loan> activeLoans = new List<Loan>();
```

или Вы не создали экземпляр `Member`:

```
public class WorkingClass
{
  public static Member member = new Member();
```

Comment: Экземпляр списка был создан

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать что поле `activeLoans` инициализировано?

Comment: @deced Покажите полный код

Comment: @deced нет, не был создан.

Comment: @D.Stark приложил код к вопросу,смотрите пожалуйста выше

Comment: WorkingClass.member не бы инициализирован, вот и ошибка.

Comment: @BearPro точно,спасибо,казалось что инициализировал его ранее...Надо передохнуть...

Comment: @Igor, new List() = new List{} Они обе инициализируют лист!